# How to autowire beans in a @Validated @Service annotated service method

Tags: spring, validation, autowired

When I annotate my Java service class, containing properties that are annotated with `@Autowired`, with Spring's `@Service`, booting the application results in an instance in which all properties are neatly wired.

If I also annotate the service class with `@Validated` (since I want method parameter validation) it results in a service bean in which all properties are null.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: They aren't `null` else the application wouldn't start. You are probably using a debugger to look at the execution. When using `@Validated` a proxy will be created for your service, this proxy will not have dependencies injected, however the object that is being wrapped will. Proxied methods will only work when those aren't `final` and they must be `public` or `protected` (it won't work for others as well).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was using the debugger to check the service and saw that the property was null. It was null. But if I invoked the getter for the property in the service it revealed that it was't null. Thanks for your comment.